# Выводится последний элемент, в то время когда надо чтоб вывелись все элементы

Tags: python, requests

```
for table in data_list:
    rank = table.get("~TR")
    team = table.get("TN")
    matches_played = table.get("TM")
    wins = table.get("TWR")
    draws = table.get("TDR")
    losses = table.get("TLR")
    goals_scored = (table.get("TG")).split(":")[0] if table.get("TG") is not None else None
    goals_missed = (table.get("TG")).split(":")[1] if table.get("TG") is not None else None
    goal_difference = table.get("TPF")
    points = table.get("TP")
    form = table.get("~LMS")
```

Всю нужную информацию я достал, кроме `form`, в котором выводится лишь последний элемент, а именно `В`, но мне надо чтобы выводились все 5 матчей в формате `В, В, В, Н, В`. `form = table.get("~LMS")[1] и т.д.` не работает. Как можно реализовать вывод всех `~LMS`?

```
~TR 1
TU q1
TUC 004682
TN Барселона
TI SKbpVP5K
TIU /ru/team/barcelona/SKbpVP5K/
TM 18
TW 15
TWR 15
TWO 0
TWP 0
TWA 0
TDR 2
TL 1
TLR 1
TLO 0
TLP 0
TLA 0
TAP 616.67
NRM 0
LK 0
TPK 2.61
TPF 31
TG 37:6
TP 47
~LMS ?
LMU upcoming
LME xWUmXzZM
LMH vJbTeCGP
LMA SKbpVP5K
LMT [b]Следующий матч:[/b]
Бетис - Барселона
1675209600
~LMS B
LMU win
LME UosYto2l
LMH nNNpcUSL
LMA SKbpVP5K
LMT [b]0:1&nbsp;[/b](Жирона - Барселона)
1674864000
~LMS B
LMU win
LME UJ6EmdJ3
LMH SKbpVP5K
LMA dboeiWOt
LMT [b]1:0&nbsp;[/b](Барселона - Хетафе)
1674345600
~LMS B
LMU win
LME vechPLzn
LMH jaarqpLQ
LMA SKbpVP5K
LMT [b]0:1&nbsp;[/b](Атлетико - Барселона)
1673136000
~LMS Н
LMU draw
LME hQJBCrit
LMH SKbpVP5K
LMA QFfPdh1J
LMT [b]1:1&nbsp;[/b](Барселона - Эспаньол)
1672444800
~LMS B
LMU win
LME 8zZpP0Jl
LMH ETdxjU8a
LMA SKbpVP5K
LMT [b]1:2&nbsp;[/b](Осасуна - Барселона)
1667865600
```

Comment: "в котором выводится лишь последний элемент, а именно В". Почему вы решили, что последний, а не первый, а может даже второй?

Comment: @Сергей Ш, таких команд 20, с уверенностью могу сказать что именно последний, так как сверял все.

Comment: Пакажите ваш data_list, а так долго можно гадать, что не так, а то у меня молотый кофе кончился.

Comment: @СергейШ, ```data_list = [{}]
url = f"https://d.soccerstand.com/ru/x/feed/df_tl_1_{match_id}"
response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
data = response.text.split("¬")
for item in data:
    key = item.split('÷')[0]
    value = item.split('÷')[-1]
    if "~TR" in key:
        data_list.append({key: value})
    else:
        data_list[-1].update({key: value})```

Comment: match_id? И где мне искать?

Comment: @СергейШ, ```headers = {"x-fsign": "SW9D1eZo"}
match_id = "dbYlw31D"```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Анализируйте.

```
import requests

headers = {"x-fsign": "SW9D1eZo"}
match_id = "dbYlw31D"

url = f"https://d.soccerstand.com/ru/x/feed/df_tl_1_{match_id}"
res = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
txt = res.text
data = txt[:txt.find('¬~HCI')].split("~TR÷")[1:]
for item in data:
    tr, *lms = item.split('¬~LMS÷')
    print('TR:', tr.split('¬')[0], 'LMS:', ' '.join(x[0] for x in lms))
```

Comment: все отлично работает, благодарю